# JAX-WS to Axis2

Tags: jax-ws, apache-axis

I have a wsdl file generated by jax-ws. Is it possible to use it with "Axis2 wsdl-to-java" generated java code ?

because I am getting this exception;

```
java.lang.InstantiationError: org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBDataSource
        at tr.com.turkcell.radius.IPToDataWithPortServiceStub$TSO_DATA.getOMElement(IPToDataWithPortServiceStub.java:5751)
        at tr.com.turkcell.radius.IPToDataWithPortServiceStub.toEnvelope(IPToDataWithPortServiceStub.java:7826)
        at tr.com.turkcell.radius.IPToDataWithPortServiceStub.process(IPToDataWithPortServiceStub.java:167)
        at com.ericsson.enk.mtv.authentication.radius.RadiusService.callRadiusWS(RadiusService.java:100)
        at com.ericsson.enk.mtv.authentication.radius.RadiusService.authenticate(RadiusService.java:62)
        at com.ericsson.enk.mtv.plugin.authentication.RadiusAuthenticationPlugin.processDefaultAuthenticationRequest(RadiusAuthenticationPlugin.java:137)
        at com.ericsson.enk.mtv.plugin.authentication.RadiusAuthenticationPlugin.authenticate(RadiusAuthenticationPlugin.java:96)
        at com.ericsson.mtv.bric.bl.AuthenticationBusinessDelegateImpl.authenticate(AuthenticationBusinessDelegateImpl.java:244)
        at com.ericsson.mtv.bric.bl.AuthenticationBusinessDelegateImpl.authenticate(AuthenticationBusinessDelegateImpl.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:112)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:166)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.EJB3InterceptorsInterceptor.invoke(EJB3InterceptorsInterceptor.java:63)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:54)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
        at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInOurTx(TxPolicy.java:79)
        at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:191)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
        at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:95)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
        at org.jboss.aspects.security.AuthenticationInterceptor.invoke(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:77)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptor.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptor.java:110)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:46)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.asynchronous.AsynchronousInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousInterceptor.java:106)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.service.ServiceContainer.dynamicInvoke(ServiceContainer.java:376)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invokeLocal(IsLocalInterceptor.java:81)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invoke(IsLocalInterceptor.java:72)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.service.ServiceRemoteProxy.invoke(ServiceRemoteProxy.java:98)
        at $Proxy811.authenticate(Unknown Source)
        at com.ericsson.mtv.bric.common.authentication.AuthenticationFilter.authenticate(AuthenticationFilter.java:171)
        at com.ericsson.mtv.bric.common.authentication.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:179)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

What do I need to do ? Should I generate the java code using jax-ws tools ? Or here is the problem is something else ?

Comment: We can probably help if you post the wsdl

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is likely that this particular error occurs because of a mismatch between the Axis2 version used to generate and build the code and the version used at runtime. Which Axis2 version(s) do you use?

Comment: I have generate and created the code at axis 1.6.1 but the code that depends that jar is axis 1.4.1. I think that would be the issue. Thanks Man.

I will check and let you know the results.

Comment: you are correct. fixed with using the required axis2 version.

Answer (score 0):

you could try `wsimport` command. Here are the [wsimport docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html)